# how can i use a variable as index in getResourceId(int index, int defValue);

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-resources

I use below code to define buttons background:

```
TypedArray bottombuttons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.bottombuttons );

button0.setBackgroundResource(bottombuttons .getResourceId(index, 1));
```

where `index` is a variable comes from shared activity

```
int index = themePref.getInt("index", 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is i had to make changes in `onResume()` not in `onCreate()`